# how to make a normal width of the cells,when some of them are normal and all other is too wide?

Tags: tables, width

i tried to make table that looks like this:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/3qa5JQt.png]

I wrote this:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/4oRGBoS.png]

But i did something wrong and the result was

[image: https://i.imgur.com/9gL27zC.png]

What did i do wrong (or didn't) and how i can fix it?

```
\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=3cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{multirow}
\sloppy
\parindent=1,5cm
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
\multirow{2}{*}{Режим работы}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{Прямая передача энергии}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Обратная передача энергии}&\\
\cline{2-7}
 $U_{1}$,B /> &$I_{1}$,A&&&& \\ 
\hline 
• & • & •& & & & \\ 
\hline 
• & • & •& & & & \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a Minimal Working Example.

Comment: I made a post in accordance with this http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2136/how-can-i-upload-an-image-to-be-included-in-a-question-or-answer. i hope i did thats right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{extsizes}%пакет для 14 шрифта
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%кодировка
\usepackage[russian]{babel}%кириллица
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}%кодировка теха

\usepackage{multirow}%объединение строки
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\hspace{0pt}\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{@{}|c|C{1.75cm}|C{1.75cm}|C{1.75cm}|C{1.75cm}|C{1.75cm}|C{1.75cm}|@{}}
\hline 
\multirow{3}{*}{Режим работы} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Прямая передача энергии} &  \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Обратная передача энергии} \\
 & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{$U_{1}$,B />} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{$I_{1}$,A} \\\cline{2-7}
   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ }  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ } & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ }& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ } & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ }&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{ } \\ 
\hline 
• & • & •& & & & \\ 
\hline 
• & • & •& & & & \\ 
\hline 
• & • & •& & & & \\ 
\hline 
• & • & •& & & & \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
\multirow{2}{*}{Режим работы}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{Прямая передача энергии}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Обратная передача энергии}&\\
\cline{2-7}
 $U_{1}$,B /> &$I_{1}$,A&&&& \\ 
\hline 
• & • & •& & & & \\ 
\hline 
• & • & •& & & & \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes,thats what i tried to do,ty!

Comment: \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\hspace{0pt}\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}} What this line does?

Comment: See figure below.

Answer (score 2):

Is it something like this you want?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier, erewhon} \usepackage[left=2cm,right=3cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\sloppy
\parindent=1,5cm
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.333}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|*{6}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}}
    \hline
    Режим работы & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Прямая передача энергии}&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{Обратная передача энергии}\\
    \cline{2-7}
    $U_{1}$,B /> &$I_{1}$,A&&&& \\
    \hline
    • & • & • & & & & \\
    \hline
    • & • & • & & & & \\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that is it,ty.